# Find the Spectra of this Bounded Linear Operator

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $X$ denote the space $L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ of all (equivalence classes of) Lebesgue integrable functions $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ with the norm $||f||_{1} = \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(t)|dt$. Let $T \in B(X)$ be defined by

$$ (Tf)(t)=f(t+1), \, \, \, \, f \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}), t \in \mathbb{R}  $$

Find the point spectrum, the approximate spectrum and the spectrum of T.

I have managed to show that $T$ is a unitary operator which means the spectrum must lie in the unit circle $S^{1}$. I am also fairly sure the point spectrum must be empty as it would required an eigenvector which is not integrable over $\mathbb{R}$.

I am struggling to see what to do to find the approximate point spectrum or the spectrum in general.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Do you mean $L^2$ or $L^1$? Because "unitary" is a notion only defined for operators between Hilbert spaces. In the case of $L^2$ note that the Fourier transform $\mathcal F: L^2(\Bbb R)\to L^2(\Bbb R)$ is a unitary isomorphism and calculate $\mathcal F^{-1}\circ T\circ\mathcal F$. This should make the spectrum clear to you. For $L^1$ you can use this previous result to guide you to what the spectrum must be and to find "approximating eigenvectors" $f_n$ with $(\lambda - T)f_n\to0$ for the appropriate $\lambda$.